# Post Request Errors - Ruby and HTTParty

Tags: ruby, json, httparty

I'm trying to make a simple post request using ruby and the httparty gem but I keep getting 401 (unauthorized) or 500 (internal server) in response. I have successfully tested the request out on Chrome extension - DHC (Dev Http Client), which consistently returns 200 responses.

My script:

```
require "json"
require "httparty"

file = JSON.parse File.read('file.json')

response = HTTParty.post("https://api.placeholder/uri", {
  :body => file,
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json", "Authorization" => "token example-placeholder-token" }
})

puts response.body
puts response.code
puts response.message
```

The two errors returned are:

```
➜  directory  ruby file.rb
{"valid":false}
401
Unauthorized
➜  directory  ruby file.rb
{"valid":false}
500
Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Any chance maybe in chrome some session cookie is allowing you to access the API while in httparty considering you don't have it, you are not able to access it? (and yeah maybe there is an issue with the token). Because from your description, the problem is probably with the API, because you reach the server to get 401/500, so HTTParty is actually working, there is something wrong either with params passed or with the API itself

Comment: Ok thanks @Fire-Dragon-DoL will check with the API "administrator", but I am not optimistic as I don't think he specialises in Ruby.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately is really hard to help you without knowing the API

Comment: Not to worry @Fire-Dragon-DoL. This is my first time working intensively with a JSON API but it seems to be a uniquely troublesome one, as the tokens appears to expire very quickly. "Logging" in often to retrieve fresh tokens solves this problem in DHC. So as you say, perhaps it is a problem at their end, or the API simply doesn't like requests coming through with Ruby files run in the command line?

Comment: I don't think Ruby is an issue at all. APIs are designed **not** to run through browsers only, otherwise you can't use them in phone/tablet apps or even software that is not browser based. It would seem really weird if they expect a browser header when performing the request (and in any case you can simulate that in Ruby). As far as I know, the only way to distinguish a browser from commandline/whatever as long as you set headers properly, is to send an html page with some javascript on it. But considering this API is returning JSON, it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugged for a simpler post request, you have to be careful about sending/receiving json with ruby (you can run into trouble with conventional ajax approach when using html too). So its much easier to give it the most "agnostic" file format possible - text (or string), and the most generic key/value pair format, which I think is this: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

This finally gave me a valid 200 response in console (n.b. not my original request as a little bit more complex - but still "proof of concept"):

```
require "json"
require "httparty"

response = HTTParty.post("https://api.placeholder-uri",
  {
  :body => { :user => "placehodler-username", :password => "placeholder-password" }.to_json,
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
  })  

puts response.body
puts response.code
puts response.message
```

Thanks to this ajax tutorial: https://www.airpair.com/js/jquery-ajax-post-tutorial for providing clue to solve this.